# How to compile wxsqlite3 and sqlite to get encryption support

Tags: c++, encryption, sqlite, wxwidgets

I'm working on a c++ project based on wxWidgets. Using wxSqlite3 for accessing sqlite database, and it is working fine. But I wanted to add some encryption for database, here I have problems with accessing encrypted db via wxSqlite3. As far as I know, sqlite doesn't support encryption by default, but wxSqlite3 somehow included encryption functionality. Could anyone who has experience, share their knowledge and practice on how to compile sqlite and wxSqlite3 in order to be able to access encryption functions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The encryption extension coming with wxSQLite3 is open source and offers AES-128 or AES-256 encryption (to be chosen at compile time). Guidance how to compile SQLite with encryption support can be found for example [here](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=27217).

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. I will try and post the results here.

Comment: How about WINFORM C#? I referenced to System.Data.SQLite.dll or Nuget, but failed to connect encrypted db3 due to SEE license issue (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.115.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=433d9874d0bb98c5' or one of its dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

The author of sqlite sells a package including encryption. He's a very nice gentleman and I encourage you to support him by buying a copy. I am not associated with that project in any way.

Comment: **Jay**, thanks for your suggestion. But I'm interested in some open-source solutions :-).